# Use REST interface for internal Google AppEngine queries

Tags: google-app-engine, rest

I have started writing a REST API for my Google AppEngine application. I read a good article on architecting REST applications that suggested I encapsulate my data services behind a REST api. Considering I'd like to be prepared to move to an architecture like Amazon Web Services if the prototype gains traction this level of encapsulation makes sense.

The idea is a request comes in for a web-page and the application server accepts the HTTP request. Then the application server itself makes a HTTP REST request to the database server instead of going directly through Datastore objects. In the case of Google AppEngine it is actually the same server but it would be easy to change what server (or cluster of servers) would actually respond to data requests.

For example:

1. http://example.com/index.html

   - results in HTTP request handled by app server
2. http://example.com/remote/data?filter=all

   - app server makes a call for data from remote server
3. App server

   - parses remote response
   - inserts data into HTML template
   - returns result to client

Note: this doesn't include any caching I'd have.

This means that for a single client HTTP request I may end up making 4-5 additional HTTP requests to build a response. Is this an architectural pattern that will work well on Google AppEngine or in general? Does Google handle internal requests (appserver instance-appserver instance) in an efficient manner?

Comment: This will cost you a lot of latency, which will make the app much less responsive to users, and it doesn't buy you anything you couldn't do with an architectural abstraction in code, without the need to make  HTTP requests to yourself.

Answer (score 3):

This pattern does not make a lot of sense for AppEngine.

Consider that there are fixed limits for some AppEngine resources, such as URLFetch that may be rapidly depleted. Also, resources that are billable, such as CPU Time, incoming bandwidth and outgoing bandwidth will all be used at a much faster rate than is reall necessary.

Moreover, it dramatically limits your AppEngine application's ability to scale. In fact, it is a negative feedback loop. As the number of external requests increases, the load on your application is going to go up *very steeply*. That is the *antithesis* of what you should be trying to achieve with your AppEngine application.

Finally, I'd suggest that this is a dubious architecture for an application on any platform, not just AppEngine. It is easy for software engineers to fall in love with abstraction, producing layers-upon-layers for the sake of values like modularity, portability, loose-coupling -- the list goes on-and-on. However, any decision made for an abstract reason that results in a very real and dramatic degradation in performance is a de facto anti-pattern.

Comment: I don't see on google's charge breakdown any cost per url fetch: http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/billing.html ... just incoming/outgoing bandwidth and CPU time. I wonder if internal requests (originating and terminating in the same app) would contribute to incoming/outgoing bandwidth ...

Comment: @James, you're right that URLFetch isn't part of the billable quota; it is fixed. Still, that presents an even greater liability to your architecture. I edited my answer to reflect billable/non-billable resources more accurately.

Comment: When I look at fixed quotas they are on the order of 500 requests per second and 3,000 URLfetch calls per minute. I feel if I get to that level of traffic I'll be most of the way to a transition to EC2 or similar. I don't think quotas will be the limiting factor but I am interested in latency and efficiency. The reason I want to do this is to enable an easier migration (avoid too much or any Datastore logic in my app code) and give me a clear path to scale the database (load balanced http requests make sense for a database that will mostly be read).

Answer (score 1):

First architecture-wise it's OK to build a REST data access layer above a storage see Microsoft's Azure docs for example http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd179423.aspx

Naturally you will encounter some sort of performance hit when moving outside the app engine and making your queries via urlfetch. I would suggest comparing the billing on datastore vs urlfetch before making the move.

If you do create a DAL to make these REST calls to a remote DB, there is no reason to actually make urlfetches to you GAE datastore. Simply write an app engine provider that makes these DB call directly with DataStore API http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/datastore/package-summary.html

Comment: I would hesitate to suggest that developers roll their own REST-based DALs just because Microsoft did it with Azure. I find it likely that Microsoft had a large number of very smart people working on making sure that end-to-end it is fully performant. It'd be much harder for an individual to come up with an implementation that was tuned enough to avoid being a bottleneck.

Comment: If I move outside of GAE I plan to move everything. I was thinking then my data would be on a separate EC2 instance with one of the fast internal IP addresses exposed using the REST DAL. This way I wouldn't need to change the application code used to access the data - I'd simply point it to the IP address of the new data instance and write an access layer (perhaps backed by a proper db instead of NoSQL)

Comment: I am sorry if i wasn't clear. I am not suggesting building your own REST datastore... as it wasn't the question.   I pointed out Azure APIs as a reference example, of what the wrapper DAL will need to handle. Naturally when migrating, this DAL wrapper is the only thing that will require changing.  Now given your wrapper API exposes the methods you require, I fail to see the benefit of the additional REST layer on your GAE datastore and not calling it directly...